# Can you edit / update a polymorphic model that's also a nested attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

I'm building a photo album where a user has many albums and each album has many photos.

Album Class

```
Class Album < ActiveRecord::Base

 attr_accessible :photos_attributes, :name
 has_many photos, :as => imageable
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos

end
```

Photo Class

```
Class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

 attr_accessible :description, :location
 belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true

end
```

Album controller methods

```
def create
  @album = current_user.albums.build(params[:album])
  if @album.save
    redirect_to @album, :notice => "Successfully created album."
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end


def edit
  @album = Album.find(params[:id])
end


def update
  @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  if @album.update_attributes(params[:album])
    redirect_to @album, :notice  => "Successfully updated album."
  else
    render :action => 'edit'
  end
end
```

Edit Album Form

```
<%= form_for @album do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :album_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo| %>
    <%= photo.label :photo_description %>
    <%= photo.text_field :description %>

    <%= photo.label :photo_location %>
    <%= photo.text_field :location %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

The problem is, when the edit form submits, the photos_attributes comes through as a hash and rails is not updating it properly.

```
  Parameters: { "album"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "name"=>"Lake Tahoe", 
                "photos_attributes"=>{"1"=>{"description"=>"Top of the Mountain!", "id"=>"2"}, 
                                      "2"=>{"description"=>"From the cabin", "id"=>"5"}}}, 
                "commit"=>"Update Ablum", "id"=>"10"}
```

The ID sent along with the photos_attributes hash is the actual ID in the photos table in the database. For whatever reason, rails is not updating the photo descriptions or locations if the user edits them. I believe it has something to do with the fact that photos are polymorphic.

Can someone please please please help?? I've been trying for a couple hours and searching all over the web and have not been able to find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: can you add the create/update methods from the controller in your question ?

Comment: Just added the Album controller methods. Nothing particularly special about them though. The create works fine and photos are created with their descriptions and locations. Weird thing is that if I edit an album and delete a photo, it works just fine. Only problem is updating model attributes of the photos (description and location). I have another model that's a nested attribute and updating it works fine. So I'm pretty sure this has to do with the fact that photos are polymorphic and is throwing things off.

Comment: check the rails server output when you edit an album .

Comment: Everything looks fine. Rails just isnt picking up the modified description or location change to the model. The parameters all look right but it's ultimately not being captured by the database and saved :( I know I can do a hack in the controller update and loop through the params hash since the data is there and update manually...just seems like Rails would be able to handle this though

Comment: you should open an issue on github https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/new .

Comment: I'll give this ticket a day or two and if nobody has any good solutions, I'll file a ticket on github. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Exactly the same problem here! How did you get on with this? Is the ticket up on github?

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on what version of rails are you on. I believe < 3.2 requires the autosave attribute on the has_many association. You may just want to add to be safe and see if that does the trick.

Also, check your logs to make sure your not getting any warnings during the request.